# Error when i try to update a member of a table

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

this is my ProdottoController:

```
package it.catalogo.controller;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import it.catalogo.model.Prodotto;
import it.catalogo.repository.ProdottoRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/prodotto")
public class ProdottoController {

    @Autowired
    private ProdottoRepository repo;
    
    @GetMapping("/lista")
    public ModelAndView list( @RequestParam(name = "id", required = false) String idProdotto, ModelMap mm) {        


        if(idProdotto!=null) {
            Optional<Prodotto> p =  repo.findById(Integer.parseInt(idProdotto));
            mm.addAttribute("prodottoDaModificare",p);
        }
        
        return new ModelAndView("prodotti", "listaProdotti", repo.findAll());
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("datiProdotto") Prodotto p) {
        
        repo.save(p);
        return "redirect:/prodotto/lista";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/update")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("datiProdotto") Prodotto p) {
        
        repo.save(p);
        return "redirect:/prodotto/lista";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(@RequestParam("id") String id) {

        repo.deleteById(Integer.parseInt(id));
        
        return "redirect:/prodotto/lista";
    }
}
```

Prodotto entity:

```
package it.catalogo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Prodotto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
    
    @Column(name = "descrizione")
    private String descrizione;

    @Column(name = "prezzo")
    private Integer prezzo;
    
    
    
    public Prodotto(String nome, String descrizione, Integer prezzo) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }
    public Prodotto() {
        super();
    }
    
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }
    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }
    public Integer getPrezzo() {
        return prezzo;
    }
    public void setPrezzo(Integer prezzo) {
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

This is the view (Freemarker):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Catalogo prodotti</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Catalogo prodotti</h1>
        
        <#if prodottoDaModificare?? >
        <h2>Modifica del prodotto - ${prodottoDaModificare.nome}</h2>
        <div style="margin: 20px">
            <form method="POST"  action="update" id="datiProdotto">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${prodottoDaModificare.id}"/>
                <div>
                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome" value="${prodottoDaModificare.nome}" id="nome">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="descrizione">Descrizione</label>
                    <input type="text" name="descrizione" value="${prodottoDaModificare.descrizione}" id="descrizione">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="prezzo">Prezzo</label>
                    <input type="number" name="prezzo" value="${prodottoDaModificare.prezzo}" id="prezzo">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="invia" value="Salva modifiche"/S>
                </div>
            
            </form>
        </div>
        <#else>

        <h2>Nuovo prodotto</h2>
        <div style="margin: 20px">
            <form method="POST"  action="add" id="datiProdotto">
            
                <div>
                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome" value="" id="nome">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="descrizione">Descrizione</label>
                    <input type="text" name="descrizione" value="" id="descrizione">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="prezzo">Prezzo</label>
                    <input type="number" name="prezzo" value="" id="prezzo">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="invia" value="Aggiungi"/>
                </div>
            
            </form>
        </div>

        </#if>
        <hr>

        <h2>Lista prodotti</h2>
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Descrizione</th>
                        <th>Prezzo</th>
                        <th>Azioni</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <#list listaProdotti as prodotto>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>${prodotto.nome}</td>
                        <td>${prodotto.descrizione}</td>
                        <td>${prodotto.prezzo}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="delete?id=${prodotto.id}">Elimina</a>
                            <a href="lista?id=${prodotto.id}">Modifica</a>
                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </#list>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i try to update a value into the table i've the following error:

**FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> prodottoDaModificare.nome [in template "prodotti.ftl" at line 15, column 47] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${prodottoDaModificare.nome} [in template "prodotti.ftl" at line 15, column 45] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToTextualCommon(EvalUtil.java:481) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:401) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:370) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.calculateInterpolatedStringOrMarkup(DollarVariable.java:100) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:63) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:347) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:353) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:353) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:326) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:391) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:304) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:255) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:179) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)**

Comment: please add more descriptive details in your Q,what you did, what happened etc,just dont copy paste all your code in here and ask whats is the issue :)

Comment: Yes, i've a form to insert a new product (name description and price) (the method is add) and under this form i've a table shows all products (see the method list into controller). Into the table i've modify and delete and when i click modify i want to update the selected product. So into controller (method list) i checked the id. If it's present, insert into model map as prodottoDaModificare and i use update method to modify it.  When i click Modify, i've the exc
PS: I USE CRUDREPOSITORY  @namila007

Comment: hi, please check your controller find api code, its not completed. after the line `mm.addAttribute("prodottoDaModificare",p);` add `return mm;`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you do `mm.addAttribute("prodottoDaModificare",p)`, `p` is not a `Prodotto` object, but an `Option`. And of course, `Option` has no `nome` property. Use `mm.addAttribute("prodottoDaModificare",p.orElse(null))` (or if the object must be there, then `orElseThrow`).